# Guidance on guarding against nils with ruby collections and active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

With active record, I believe there is a difference when calling:

```
User.find(23)
```

versus

```
User.where("...")
```

If the first case, will this be sufficient to gaurd against the record not being found?

```
u = User.find(234)

if u
  # assume record found??
end
```

**Or should I be checking for nil? and/or persisted?**

And in the second case with a where clause, I understand that I will get a collection back, and an empty array if nothing is found:

```
users = User.where("...")

if users.blank?
  # assuming at least 1 user model in the collection
end
```

Is this correct or is there a better way?

Now with regular ruby collections, you have to always check for nils before assigning like:

```
first_item = some_collection[0] unless some_collection.nil? || some_collection.empty?
# or I can use blank?
```

Is this basically all there is to know about guarding against nils when it comes to collections in both ruby and active record?

Comment: This is a case where toying with the Rails console can take you a long way. Just start it up and mess around.

Answer (score 2):

1. `User.find(23)` will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if a User with id 23 does not exist. If you prefer to get nil instead you can use `User.find_by_id(23)`.
2. Correct. There are other ways, like calling `#empty?` or `#count` on the relation, but they're essentially the same.
3. To get the first item from an existing but potentially empty collection, you can do this:

   ```
   first_item = some_collection.first
   ```

   which will return nil if some_collection is empty. This is somewhat different from your example, which will check for a nil collection and won't change first_item at all if some_collection is nil or empty. But that's a much less common use case. (Also, yes, the Rails `#blank?` method will return true when called on an empty collection.)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the not found error and handle it:

```
begin
  foo = Foo.find(params[:id])   
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to somewhere_else_url
end
```